# Database / systemctl issues after switch to 15.04

Tags: 15.04, postgresql, mongodb

I recently updated Ubuntu to 15.04.  Since then, I've been having issues starting and stopping postgres and mongodb, which also affects apt-get when it tries to install or uninstall them.  Here's the output from apt-get when trying to process an uninstall request for mongodb:

```
Setting up mongodb-server (1:2.6.3-0ubuntu7) ...
systemctl: unrecognized option '--job-mode=ignore-dependencies'
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongodb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
    mongodb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The line `systemctl: unrecognized option '--job-mode=ignore-dependencies'` also occurs when I type `sudo service postgres (mongodb) start`.  Any help would be appreciated - many thanks!

Comment: Well, what's in the logs? How did you upgrade?

Comment: Which logs?  The problem comes up in multiple places.  I upgraded with `do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

The default init system in 15.04 is `systemd` (changed from upstart), and I believe this is the root of the problem.  You can either alter the services (you can try installing the Debian packages instead for example) or you can install upstart to make the existing packaged work again:

```
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
```

Once installed, reboot and see if your services will now start/stop again etc.